# I have bunch of error installing npm in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, git, npm, bitbucket

I searched really much forums allready to finde something like this, and I found similar things but none helped me. Make you know whats up.

I just installed fresh ubuntu, and there I installed vim, git and node.js. Now I want to install also npm, but then I get error. A bunch of them tbh:

```
kuba@ubuntu:~/lgv$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated tsml@1.0.1: no longer maintained
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as
    _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git resetting remote /home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f because of error: { Error: Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit 
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit  signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone
    --template=/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git /home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f: Cloning into bare repository '/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates
    --mirror https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git /home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f: remote: Invalid username or password
npm ERR! git clone
    --template=/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git /home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git/'
npm ERR! Linux
    4.18.0-15-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone
    --template=/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git /home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/home/kuba/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-bitbucket-org-lgv-g12-lgv-config-git-d9c0735f'...
npm ERR! remote: Invalid username or password
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git/'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/kuba/lgv/npm-debug.log
kuba@ubuntu:~/lgv$
```

Maybe you know what I messed up. Its allready my secound linux machine I get those errors from, and nothing can really help me to fix the issue.

Comment: `Invalid username or password`  appears in the log after `git clone`. It might be related to that.

Comment: Is there something unclear about the error message? `fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/lgv-g12/lgv-config.git/'` is clear that your authentication data is invalid for the repository you're attempting to clone.

Comment: I dont want to clone anything whatsoever, I just want to install apm. Thats all, and after I type "install amp" this whole bunch of error appeares with error messages which I dont understand

Comment: Something is requesting that repo, though. It's a private repo and you aren't passing any authentication, so Bitbucket is rejecting the attempted clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an Ubuntu machine (and Debian etc.) using apt-get, install npm via:

`sudo apt-get install npm`

You used the command

`npm install`

This command is used to install the dependencies of your node.js project, stated in your package.json.